# RHEL 8 authentication required window is not taking correct password

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, gnome, password

So I'm running RHEL 8 and every now and then I get an issue where the Authentication Window will not take my password. I know I am entering it correctly because it is the same password I use to login to the system. Checked /var/log/secure but didn't see anything useful. Could it be related to pam.d?

Comment: By authentication window, do you mean the gdm login screen? https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5011721 Have you also looked at `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: Kinda - but instead of Authentication error it says, Sorry that didn't work, please try again. /var/log/messages reports VNC authentication error. I checked that link but it's referring to a file that does not exist for me under /usr/lib/systemd/user/vncserver@.service. I'm guessing they changed it since RHEL 8.2. I'm on 8.6. But at least I know now it's related to my VNC configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with RHEL 8.4, 8.5 with the Gnome environment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1971534 (that went away)

I was still able to SSH remotely to the machine. So I re-installed and enabled the "Workstation" GUI which seem to remove the issue (at least workaround)

```
$ sudo dnf group list

Available Environment Groups:
   Server
   Minimal Install
   Custom Operating System
   Virtualization Host
Installed Environment Groups:
   Server with GUI
   Workstation
Installed Groups:
   Container Management
   Headless Management
Available Groups:
   Legacy UNIX Compatibility
   Development Tools
   .NET Core Development
   Graphical Administration Tools
   Network Servers
   RPM Development Tools
   Scientific Support
   Security Tools
   Smart Card Support
   System Tools
$ 
$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical
$ sudo reboot
```

https://www.tecmint.com/install-gui-on-rhel-8/